# avahi daemon constantly needs restarting

Tags: ssh, dns, hostname, avahi

I have Ubuntu 11 running on a Thinkpad W520. Things work great, but not avahi-daemon. It seems that my laptop becomes invisible (ssh user@hostname.local can't find the laptop) to other computers on the network. Then I have to `sudo service avahi-daemon restart`. It seems I have to do this every day or two. Is there a way to avoid having to restart avahi-daemon so often?

Comment: You can use systemd and add a option to RestartOn=always